# Embed Google Plus Community?

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

I've noticed there are some similar questions on Stack Overflow, but they either aren't exactly what I'm trying to do or are outdated answers.

I am the owner of a Google Plus community and I wish to embed that community on our site, similar to how one can embed a Twitter page on a website and users can see the latest posts (see http://ffsplit.com for an example of that)

Can this be done with a Google Plus community? Does Google have an API for this? Or maybe there is a quick and easy iframe method? I am willing to use PHP or jQuery but would prefer to stick to HTML/Javascript.

In this question [Google Plus Embedded Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783276/google-plus-embedded-post) a JSFiddle by Fri is provided with an embedded post. This is close to what I want but not exactly. I want to embed an entire community, rather than just one post by one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no solution. There are no widgets for communities and the [API does not provide access to communities](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=639).